# Designate a file location based on a value in certain cell

Tags: excel, vba

I can change the filename based on a certain cell value. I am trying to change the file location based off the value in a certain cell.

There is a drop down in "B6" and a folder for each option available.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub SFVTEST()

Dim filepath

filepath = """T:\Restricted - Department\GLA_Shortcuts\Reagent and Column _ Validation\" & Range("B6") & "\" & Range("T26") & ".csv"""

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filepath,_ FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Getting a

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed"

Line of Code with error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error is in switching between strings and variables. Strings are surrounded by double quotes, variables aren't. And when switching between the two, use an '&'.

```
Sub SaveForValidation()
'
' SaveforValidation Macro
'

' File Name Formula Found in T26 in white text.
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "T:\Restricted - Department\GLA_Shortcuts\Reagent and Column 
         Validation\" & Range("B6") & "\" & Range("T26") & ".csv" _
         , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

It might make sense to build the filename in a variable to make testing easier, such as:

```
Sub SaveForValidation()
Dim filepath
filepath = "T:\Restricted - Department\GLA_Shortcuts\Reagent and Column Validation\" & Range("B6") & "\" & Range("T26") & ".csv"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filepath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: This still won't compile though if `"T:\Restricted - Department\GLA_Shortcuts\Reagent and Column 
         Validation\"` is on multiple lines.

Comment: Now getting a "Run-time error '424': Object required.

Comment: It is flagging the object required on the (AciveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filepath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False)

Comment: In your comment above, you have AciveWorkbook (missing a T in Active). I'm assuming that problem isn't in your code?

Comment: Well it isn't anymore :D... Now getting Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed

Comment: Okay. Can you step through it (by hitting F8), and just after the 'filepath = ' line, see what the value is?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by see what the value is? Thanks for all the help by the way!!!!

Comment: If you're stepping through the code with F8, you'll see each line highlighted. Just after the filepath = line, put your mouseover "filepath" and see what it says. It should display the current value, and that might give you a clue to the issue.

Comment: says filepath = empty. could it be that I need to clarify Range B6 as activeworkbook or active sheet?

Comment: That probably isn't the issue. It will default to the sheet that you're running the macro from. Can you repost all of your code, along with the current error message, in the initial question?

Comment: Done, sorry tried moving this to chat but my rep is too low.

Comment: Same. Let's try it now with just one " on each side instead of """

Comment: Also, remove the underscore in Reagant and Column Validation. That's a relic of when it was placed on two lines.

Comment: It's not there in the code. just put that in to try to illustrate it is one line of code. There is a picture attached at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Alright. Did you try again with just one doublequote on each end?

Comment: Yep no change?.

Comment: Alright. Try F8 again to view the value of filepath. Make sure you go one line PAST the filepath line and then hover over filepath.

Comment: So if the AciveWorkbook line is highlighted then it has part of the filepath displayed. However it doesn't display the whole line because it is too long. Isn't there a way to type it into the "immediate" box to get it to read out the path?

Comment: Definitely. Just type "?filepath" in the immediate window.

Comment: "T:\Restricted - Department\GLA_Shortcuts\Reagent and Column Validation\_4000_12\MPC RL# C-13500 Lot 123456.csv"..................... That looks right, Think the underscores are causing the issues in the _4000_12 part?

Comment: Look at Reagant and Column _ Validation...that's not correct, is it? the underscore, I mean.

Comment: yeah that was wrong but I fixed it and no change. and for some reason the comment above isn't showing one of the "\" it should be it is in the code though

Comment: Ok just noticed something it is saving the file with the correct name and when I go into the File menu it looks like the right pathway. But it isn't there. and when I click open folder it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Got it!!!! Thanks for all your help. I went back and checked the file pathways and there was a one of them was reagent validations compared to reagent validation...

Answer (score 0):

The above code you have the file name to be saved as .csv but you want it to be a macro-enabled workbook...

```
Sub SaveForValidation()

    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = "T:\Restricted - Department\GLA_Shortcuts\Reagent and Column Validation\" & Range("B6") & "\" & Range("T26") & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filepath, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

I personally use file format # instead of words. 52 = .xlsm

For other types, see below
51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro’s in 2007, .xlsx)

52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro’s in 2007, .xlsm)

50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007 with or without macro’s, .xlsb)

56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007, .xls)